# C structure with bits printing in hexadecimal

Tags: c

I have defined a structure as below

```
   struct {
        UCHAR   DSatasetMGMT : 1;
        UCHAR   AtriburDeallocate : 1;
        UCHAR   Reserved6 : 6;
        UCHAR   Reserved7 : 7;
        UCHAR   DSatasetMGMTComply : 1;
    }DatasetMGMTCMDSupport;
```

It is a 2 byte structure represented in bits. How should I print the whole 2 bytes of structure in hexadecimal. I tried

```
"DatasetMGMTCMDSupport                          :   0x%04X\n"
```

And

```
0x%04I64X\n
```

But not getting expected result.

I am getting 0x3DC18003 with 0x%04X\n while the correct data is 0x8003 "

I am using 64 bit windows system.

I need to know how to print 2 byte structure in hexadecimal.

Comment: You can try `0x%04hX` but without knowing your exact code it's hard to help

Comment: You can't treat the bit-fields as a single integer reliably.  You'd have to use a union of the bit-fields and the correct-sized integer.  Then you can set the bit-fields and pass the integer to `printf()`.  You're getting garbage because you're fibbing to `printf()`.  Don't fib to the compiler or the library — it rarely works well.

Comment: "the correct printing should be"? Why? The order of fields in a bitfield is implementation defined. Also, how do you print? How do you provide the 16 bits to `printf`? How large is `unsigned int` in your system? With `%x` You tell the compiler to take an `unsigned int` value while you only provide 16 bits with is very likely not the same size on modern PCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `0x%04hx\n`. This tells printf to print out only the two bytes. You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Length_field

In contrast, the I64 in `0x%04I64X\n` tells printf to print out a 64 bit integer, which is 8 bytes, and `0x%04X\n` tells it to print out a default-size integer, which might be 4 bytes on your system.

The width `04` specifies a *minimum* width. Since the value needs more digits, they are printed.

Comment: @raj Be aware that `hx` formats a `short int` which is at least 2 bytes wide, but it could be more than 2 bytes and in that case some garbage data may be displayed. It would be more correct to use `"0x%04"PRIx16`.

Answer (score 2):

From a C Standard point of view, you cannot rely on a particular layout of bit fields. Hence, any solution will at best have implementation-defined behaviour.

That being said, your expected output can be obtained. The structure fits in 2 bytes and if you print `sizeof(DatasetMGMTCMDSupport)` it should give the result 2.

The byte representation of `DatasetMGMTCMDSupport` can be printed and that is what you were attempting, but since your system has integer size 4, two additional bytes are included. To fix this, the following can be done:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...
    uint16_t a;
    memcpy(&a, &DatasetMGMTCMDSupport, sizeof(a));
    printf("0x%04X", (unsigned)a);
```

This copies the 2 bytes of `DatasetMGMTCMDSupport` into a 2-byte integer variable and prints the hexadecimal representation of those 2 bytes only. If you are on a little-endian system, you should see `0x8003`.

A more general approach would be to directly print the bytes of `DatasetMGMTCMDSupport`:

```
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(DatasetMGMTCMDSupport); i++)
    {
        printf("%02X", (unsigned)((unsigned char *)&DatasetMGMTCMDSupport)[i]);
    }
```

This will most likely print `0380` (notice the byte order: first byte printed first).

To reverse the byte order is straightforward:

```
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(DatasetMGMTCMDSupport); i++)
    {
        printf("%02X", (unsigned)((unsigned char *)&DatasetMGMTCMDSupport)[sizeof(DatasetMGMTCMDSupport)-1-i]);
    }
```

which should give `8003`.

Comment: @neilsen Yes actually the structure is a part of a very large structure, And I need to use the loop for every structure to follow your approach,  But I am sure it will work and very thankful for such a good explanation. However, 0x%04hx worked in my case.